# jQuery - get data from different types of elements within multiple divs

Tags: jquery

Consider the following block of HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <select>
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <select>
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

The divs with class "wrapper" contain multiple types of elements (selects, inputs, etc...) I need something that starts with

```
$('.wrapper').each(function () { 
   // code that collects select, input data
});
```

that puts the data in a multidimensional array ( a['select option', 'input data'] ).

As Rory McCrossan pointed out in his accepted answer, I meant that I need an array of objects and not a multidimensional array.

Comment: Looks like you would have better to serialize `.wrapper` elements, e.g:https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:input` selector:

```
var values = {};
$('.wrapper :input').each(function () { 
    values[$(this).prop('name')] = $(this).val();
});
```

> :input
>   Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.

More info on `:input` in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

---

Based on your comments, you need the data as an array of objects (note this not the same as a multi-dimensional array). To achieve this you would need to two loops. One to cover the `.wrapper` elements, and another to find the `:input` elements within them. Try this:

```
var values = [];
$('.wrapper').each(function () { 
    var wrapperValues = {};
    $(this).find(':input').each(function() {
        wrapperValues[$(this).prop('name')] = $(this).val();
    });
    values.push(wrapperValues);
});
```

Comment: will `select` be selected?

Comment: i see :) i want thinking only input element will be selected learned something today :)

Comment: @guradio Be aware that's a jQuery selector, not valid in CSS

Comment: This only gives me the value from the LAST input element from the LAST .wrapper div.

Comment: Are you sure? It is completely agnostic of any wrapping elements, as you can see in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/09zro7f6/. Can you post a demo of the problem, along with your HTML and JS

Comment: Yeah, that fiddle works for me too, but I don't use the name attribute anywhere. It doesn't matter for me as long as i get array[0] = ['select1', 'input1', 'input2'] , array[1] = ['select2', 'input3', 'input4']

Comment: Are you using my code? I put the values in to an object instead of multiple arrays.

Comment: Yes, that works, it gives me {"foo":"1","bar":"ets","fizz":"3","buzz":"test"}. The last thing is that this data to be in a multidimensional array: array[0] = {"foo":"1","bar":"ets"} array[1] = {"fizz":"3","buzz":"test"}

Comment: I updated my answer for you. Also note that the format you've specified there is an array of objects, not a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed. And indeed, the format what I meant is supposed to be an array of objects, my bad...

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
var finalVal = [];
$('.wrapper').each(function () { 
   $("input, select, textarea").each(function () {
       finalVal.push($(this).val());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [];
$('.wrapper').children().each(function () { 
   // code that collects select, input data
  arr.push($(this).val());
});

$('#value').html(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value='12'>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value='34'>
</div>
<div id='value'></div>
```

Try this way use [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

> Description: Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way imho would be to serailize all inputs inside wrapper elements:

```
var datas = $('.wrapper').find(':input').attr('name', function(){
    return this.nodeName.toLowerCase();
}).serializeArray();
```

But that's suppose you don't have attribute name specified for these inputs and that you don't want to override it.